# Creating cpp multiplication table using for loop

Tags: c++

[output should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9YCn.png) I hope u guys can help me..
Here's the code that I tried:

```
int main() {
    int x,y;
    for (x=1; x<=10; x++) {
        cout << x << "|";
        for (y=1; y<=10; y++) {
            cout << x*y << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: That formatting is atrocious, and from what's been shown, it just seems like you need to think on it a bit longer before coming here for an answer. As an Intro adjunct myself, you're getting a super-simple midterm.

Comment: Why do you have the return statement in the for loop?

Comment: Read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html), see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), read the documentation of your compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (maybe [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Comment: And you don't need `std::endl` (which forces a flush of the stream after printing the newline) - all you need is an `"\n"` to print a newline

Answer (score 1):

Your program is terminating just after the first iteration of the loop, the reason behind this is that you misplaced `return 0` inside the loop instead of putting it at the end, so your program is returning after first iteration of the loop.

here is the fix

```
int main() 
{
    int x,y;
    for (x=1; x<=10; x++)
    {
        cout<<x <<"|";
        for (y=1; y<=10; y++)
        {
            cout<<x*y<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```